# How to javadoc a constructor extending an abstract class

Tags: java, javadoc, code-documentation

I'm trying to document my Java code in the cleanest way possible, without having to copy stuff multiple times. Here is an example of what I've got, then I'll explain what I want:

```
public abstract class Toto <S extends Number>{

    /**
    * Defined value
    */
    protected S myVariable;
    protected String myWord;

    /**
    * Constructor 1
    */
    protected Toto(){
        this.myWord = "a";
    }

    /**
    * Constructor 2
    * @param number something
    */
    protected Toto(S number){
        this.myVariable = number;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

```
public class ShortToto extends Toto<Short>{

    public subToto(){
        super();
    }

    /**
    * {@link Toto#Toto(Number)}
    */
    public subToto(Short number){
        super(number);
    }
    ...
}
```

The ShortToto javadoc I get from that is a link to the method in the Toto class which is basically what I want. However, in netbeans, I'm told to add the @param for number, but it is the same thing as the one in Toto.
I don't want to redefine what number is since it is already defined in Toto, but I also don't what Netbeans to tell me I need to add the @param tag.

An idea I had was to add a javadoc for myVariable in Toto, add an @param number tag in ShortToto and link it. However, in this case I get a link to the myVariable doc, while I would like to only get the definition. In this case "Defined value".

I hope I'm clear enough, if not, I apologize in advance, do not hesitate to ask me questions and I'll try to be clearer.

Comment: {@inheritdoc} might be what you're looking for. I use Eclipse but chances are you can turn off javadoc warnings in your settings

Answer (score -1):

If this is API documentation for other developers then my personal preference would be to either

- Copy to from the base class (a DRY violation in documentation!)
- Use the `{@link xxxx}` documentation tag

and then ignore the problem.

If it's just for your self I'd go as far as turning of the IDE warning as well